# Python - ayuda con regex

Tags: python, regex

Tengo problemas con las regex: necesito extraer lo que esta dentro de las comillas de :respuesta , o sea necesito extraer TEST1 y TEST2

```
import re

txt = '{:id 13, :tipo "texto", :etiqueta "Observaciones", :requerido false, :respuesta "TEST1"} {:id 14, :tipo "texto", :etiqueta "Observaciones", :requerido false, :respuesta "TEST2"}'

pattern = ':respuesta "(.*)"'

x = re.findall(pattern, txt)
print(x)
```

Probé de esa manera pero no estaría funcionando como necesito.

Comment: ¿No has pensado en castear el string a diccionarios y sacar los valores como diccionario? Pienso que te queda más cómodo para maneja los datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intentemos con esto:

```
txt = '{:id 13, :tipo "texto", :etiqueta "Observaciones", :requerido false, :respuesta "TEST1"} {:id 14, :tipo "texto", :etiqueta "Observaciones", :requerido false, :respuesta "TEST2"}'

re.findall(r':respuesta\s"(.*?)"', txt)
```

Y obtenemos lo siguiente:

```
['TEST1', 'TEST2']
```

Veamos un poco más de cerca la aproximación.

Nuestra expresión regular es `:respuesta\s"(.*?)"`, en donde tenemos los caracteres:

- `\s` que nos indican que va a haber un espacio. Esto lo ponemos para hacerlo más claro a la vista puesto que un simple  , no se nota tanto como un `\s`
- luego tenemos `"(.*?)"` utilizamos el signo de interrogación para indicarle que el match no se pasé de glotón y sólo llegue hasta antes de la primera comilla doble.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, funciono como necesitaba.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el [Non-Greedy Qualifier](https://docs.python.org/es/3/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy) `*?` para obtener el texto hasta el siguiente `"`.

El problema que se te presenta es que al haber `"` posteriores, el calificador `*` sigue consumiendo caracteres después del primer `"`.

```py
import re

txt = '{:id 13, :tipo "texto", :etiqueta "Observaciones", :requerido false, :respuesta "TEST1"} {:id 14, :tipo "texto", :etiqueta "Observaciones", :requerido false, :respuesta "TEST2"}'

pattern = ':respuesta "(.*?)"'

x = re.findall(pattern, txt)

print(x)
```

Salida

```
['TEST1', 'TEST2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Un patrón simple que funciona es:

```
pattern = ':respuesta "([^"]*)"'
```

La idea es que lo buscado es cualquier cosa que no sea una cremilla doble. Este patrón no funciona si la :respuesta trae cremillas dobles incorporadas.

**Comprobación**

```
import re
txt = '{:id 13, :tipo "texto", :etiqueta "Observaciones", :requerido false, :respuesta "TEST1"} {:id 14, :tipo "texto", :etiqueta "Observaciones", :requerido false, :respuesta "TEST2"}'

pattern = ':respuesta "([^"]*)"'
x = re.findall(pattern, txt)
print(x)
```

produce

```
['TEST1', 'TEST2']
```

que es una lista de todos los términos encontrados en el string.